# php-fpm status page show listen queue length as 0

Tags: php-fpm

I have configured php-fpm to use a `listen.backlog = 128` but when I view the FPM status page, I see `listen queue len: 0`

It's an AWS EC2 server running `Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-1058-aws x86_64)`
I am using the default `/etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` but I have added an extra config file (`/etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d/x-www-local.conf`) which has the following contents:

```
[www]

listen.backlog = 128
pm = static
pm.max_children = 10
pm.max_requests = 500
pm.status_path = /status
```

I have no idea why the listen queue length is still showing as 0. Any ideas?

Comment: There are some bug reports concerning this https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=80739

Answer (score 0):

I found that this is caused by using unix socket (e.g. `listen = /run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock`).

Switching to TCP socket (e.g. `listen = 127.0.0.1:9000`) fixes this.

Comment: To check listen queue for unix socket, use `ss -ln | { head -1; grep php; }` to find the current listen queue on Recv-Q.

Comment: I would not consider switching to TCP a "fix". This will generate overhead for an internal TCP connection, which can be avoided when using unix sockets. Always use unix sockets, if possible. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973942/tcp-loopback-connection-vs-unix-domain-socket-performance